# Xamarin Maps Pins Invisible

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a very strange issue where the map pins do not show up on the map.

I am using Xamarin.Forms.Maps

I am setting up a map with

```
            map = new CustomMap(
            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                    new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)), this)
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
```

Then I create an absolute layout and add map to it and set the absoluteLayout to be the content

```
        var absoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red.WithLuminosity(0.9),
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(map, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(map, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        absoluteLayout.Children.Add(map);
        absoluteLayout.Children.Add(btn);
        Content = absoluteLayout;
```

I also add an initial pin to the map

```
            PinInfo firstInfo = new PinInfo
        {
            pinId = "1",
            Description = "First Description",
        };

        var pin = new Pin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = position,
            Label = "custom pin",
            Address = "custom detail info",
            BindingContext = firstInfo,
        };

        pin.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert(pin.Label, "The address is: " + pin.Address, "Cancel");
        };

        map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

However, in the app I can see the map, but it is not zoomed to the initial area, adding pins does nothing, and I cannot see the initial Pin.

I've been trying to search online for a very long time now, but for some reason have not found anyone with a similar issue...

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are placing your `Pin`. In other words, what is stored `position`?

Try the following after adding your `Pin`:

```
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
```